# react admin GET_LIST format

Tags: express, react-admin

I try to add `react-admin` to my Express API. I would like create the first list Users. My provider is connected, but i've this message :

`The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'GET_LIST'`

But, the result of the request is this :

[image]

I don't really understand why the data format is no good.

My server side response :

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Range', 'users 0-24/324');
  res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
  res.set('X-Total-Count', 10);
  res.send({ data: db.get('users').value(), total: 10 });
});
```

Anyone have already use react-admin and can help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: What dataProvider are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In my work project, the answer to this query is this:

Response Headers: X-Total-Count: 10

Response: [{ id: 1, ... }, { id: 2, ... }, ...]

Try this:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Range', 'users 0-24/324');
  res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
  res.set('X-Total-Count', 10);
  res.send(db.get('users').value());
});
```